# Reductive Lie groups and existence of maximal compact subgroup

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, reductive-groups

I am reading Knapp's [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2453-0) "Lie groups beyond an introduction" (2nd edition). I am struggling to understand the following point. Recall that $G$ is a reductive Lie group. If the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$ is reductive and equipped with a involution and a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form $B$ on $\mathfrak g$ which is $\theta$-invariant and $Ad$-invariant and the following hold.

1. We have a decomposition $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak k\oplus \mathfrak p$ with respect to the eigenspaces of $\theta.$
2. $G$ has a compact subgroup with Lie algebra $\mathfrak k.$
3. The map $(k,\exp X)\mapsto k\exp X$ from $K\times \exp\mathfrak p$ to $G$ is a diffeomorphism.
4. The bilinear form $B_\theta (X,Y):=-B(X,\theta Y)$ is positive definite on $\mathfrak g.$
5. Every automorphism $Adg$ for $g\in G$ is inner.

From this Knapp concludes that $K$ has to be a maximal compact subgroup. he argues as the following (Page 446). Let $K$ is properly contained in a compact subgroup $K_1$. Take $k_1\in K_1\setminus K.$ Then for some $k\in K$ and $X\in\mathfrak p$, we have $k\exp X=k_1$ which implies that $\exp X\in K_1.$ Since $(\exp X)^n=\exp (nX)$ is in $K_1$ the sequence $\exp(nX)$ must have a convergent subsequence. I get easily to this point. Now Knapp says that this contradicts 3.! I do not understand this. Can someone help me out?

Comment: In the topological space $K\times \exp {\mathfrak p}$ the sequence  $a_n=(1,nX)$ has no convergent subsequence.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi. Can you please explain a little more? $\mathfrak p$ has the topology of an Euclidean space and thus $nX$ must be a divergent sequence for $X\neq 0.$ But the diffeomorphism is given from $K\times \exp p$. I do not know if the exponential map is a homeomorphism on $\mathfrak p.$

Comment: Actually it is a diffeomorphism $K\times {\frak p}\to G$ (this is what Knapp means). And then you should use the definition of the product topology in $K\times {\frak p}$.

Comment: "I do not know if the exponential map is a homeomorphism on $\frak p$". Yes, it is a diffeomorphism. You should use the definition of $\frak p$.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi. One more thing. Can you suggest me some god books where I can find integration theory on semisimple Lie groups using KAK and KAN type decompositions? Helgason does not have this. Knapp has this for KAN only.

Comment: Unfortunately, no, I cannot. I do algebra only and know nothing about integration. But you can ask this in a separate question on MO.